# Arrange list by which word comes first in given sentence/string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I need the code to sort a list (of words) in the order by which they appear in a string (sentence).

For example:

```
list = ["small dog", "big dog", "medium dog"]

sentence = "Jack has a big dog not a small dog or medium dog."
```

Then the expected new_list would be:

```
new_list = ["big dog", "small dog", "medium dog"]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: And don't name your list as `list` because it is a buitlin function

Comment: what would happen for entries in `list` not found in `sentence`?

Comment: @BlackThunder I tried indexing each character in the list and then sorting the list according to their index (but was not successful :) )                                                     
                                                                                                                             and yes! you're right about the use of list but in a hurry I just wrote it quickly for the example

Comment: Please show that code as an edit on your question

Comment: @BlackThunder 'indexes = [] for l in _list: index = sentence.index(l) indexes.append(index)' and I then struggled on the next part 'for index in indexes: new_list = _list.sort(_list, key=index)' which is not callable. so, i got stuck ... :))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can sort by the position in the sentence by using [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html):

```py
_list = ['small dog', 'medium dog', 'big dog']

sentence = "Jack has a big dog not a small dog or medium dog."

new_list = sorted(_list, key=sentence.find)

['big dog', 'small dog', 'medium dog']
```

You *really* don't want to use built-in names for variables such as `list`, `dict`, `set`, etc

Comment: You don't need the lambda. You can just say key=sentence.find

Comment: @C.Nivs Thank you! and for the fast answer!